# Intercept method call arguments using JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have a number of methods that call out to an API endpoints. Each endpoint expects an array of id's with a length limit of 100. More often than not I have to make multiple calls to these endpoints (due to bad design etc) because I have batches of around 400. So in this example I end up having to fragment the id's into 4 sets and make 4 requests.

I have some low level methods that simply make the HTTP request using superagent:

```
getProducts (ids, token) {
  return Request
      .send({ ids : ids })
}
```

There are a fair few of these and I'm loathed to change them all to split up the ids into sets and instead return an array of requests.

My idea and call me out on this if it seems like a bad one was to create some form of wrapper that can intercept a call, break down the id's into sets and return an array of requests instead. Maybe something along the lines of:

```
var chunk = function (op) {
    return _.wrap(op, function (func, interceptor) {
        var args = interceptor(_.drop(arguments, 1));

        return func.apply(this, args);
    });
}
```

What I'm stuck on is how I would use this approach to first generate the sets and then the requests. It seems really hard to do if I want to preserve the signature of getProducts.

```
var requests = chunk(getProducts);
```

Is there some other technique that's geared towards this approach or is this just plain crazy? I'm open to any alternative techniques.

Answer (score 0):

```
function multiRequest(ids, token) {
    var CHUNK_SIZE = 100;
    var requests = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < ids.length; i += CHUNK_SIZE) {
        requests.push(getProducts(ids.slice(i, i + CHUNK_SIZE)));
    }
    return requests;
}
```

You can call this just like you call `getProducts` and it will return an array of requests split into groups of 100 ids.

Comment: Thanks for answering! What I was trying to avoid though was having to repeat the code above (or similar) within all of my methods. I've got about 10 that need to work in this way.